# jquery .on() executing function before event occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, namespaces

```
var MobileMenu = {
    menu: function () {
        $('#navigation').toggleClass("open");
        $('body').toggleClass("push");
    }
}    

$(function(){
    $(".icon-menu").on("click", MobileMenu.menu());
});
```

For some reason, this is immediately firing MobileMenu.menu on the page being loaded and ".icon-menu" seems to no longer have the event bound. There is no other javascript besides jquery being loaded.

Comment: You are not binding the handler, instead binding the return of `MobileMenu.menu()` as you are calling the function itself when binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MobileMenu.menu()` will call the function, You need `MobileMenu.menu` only

```
$(function(){
    $(".icon-menu").on("click", MobileMenu.menu);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.on` method isn't executing it. You are with `()`.

Use an anonymous function if you need to retain the `MobileMenu` context.

```
$(".icon-menu").on("click", function(e) {
    MobileMenu.menu(e)
});
```

---

Or use `$.proxy()`

```
$(".icon-menu").on("click", $.proxy(MobileMenu, "menu"));
```